# How to generate rectangle with user values in output?

Tags: javafx

I have seen examples of Rectangle in JavaFx. But Please can anybody Provide me the example where in output window/Scene, if user put desirable width and height, rectangle should be generated automatically.
here is my example

```
            VBox vb = new VBox(20);
            HBox h1  = new HBox(7);
            HBox h2 = new HBox(7);
            Label lebel1 = new Label("X:");
            Label lebel2 = new Label("Y:");

            TextField txt1 = new TextField();
            TextField txt2 = new TextField();

//Converting textfield to integer only    
            ChangeListener<String> forceNumberListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (!newValue.matches("\\d*"))
                  ((StringProperty) observable).set(oldValue);
            };

            txt1.textProperty().addListener(forceNumberListener);
            txt2.textProperty().addListener(forceNumberListener);

            double width = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
            double height = Double.parseDouble(txt2.getText());

            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle();
            rect1.setHeight(height);
            rect1.setWidth(width);  
            h1.getChildren().addAll(lebel1, txt1);
            h2.getChildren().addAll(lebel2, txt2);  

            vb.getChildren().addAll(h1,h2,rect1);
```

If user put any integer value in "x" as width, "y" as height, Rectangle should be generated below fields. but this code is wrong and i don't know other methods. Please

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the TextField's onkeyreleased event handler. In this app, if both TextFields have a number typed in, a rectangle will be generated. Both TextFields have an event handler that does the same thing if one of their text is changed. This does not catch for any non-double values.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication104 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();


        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setMinWidth(100);

        TextField textfield1 = new TextField();
        TextField textfield2 = new TextField();

        textfield1.setPrefWidth(50);
        textfield1.setPromptText("Enter height");
        textfield1.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {  
                if(textfield1.getText().length() > 0 && textfield2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    rectangle.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textfield1.getText()));
                    rectangle.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textfield2.getText()));
                    rectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    root.setCenter(rectangle);
                }
            }
        });



        textfield2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textfield2.setPromptText("Enter length");
        textfield2.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(textfield1.getText().length() > 0 && textfield2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    rectangle.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textfield1.getText()));
                    rectangle.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textfield2.getText()));
                    rectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    root.setCenter(rectangle);
                }
            }
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textfield1, textfield2);
        root.setLeft(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that would help.